# Ignore click on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set an "onmousedown" event handler for the body of my page. In this page there are some div elements, is it possible to ignore the clicks on these divs, and to just fire the onmousedown event handler of the body with the correct coordinates, as if the divs were not present?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want a click on a div to result in nothing, use this CSS declaration:

```
div {
pointer-events: none;
}
```

or use this to stop any event from firing by a click on a div:

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a custom class to the `div` elements you want to ignore clicks (let's say, `ignore-clicks`):

```
div.ignore-clicks {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This is simply the best solution, many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, add `stopPropagation();` to your divs to stop the click event from bubbling.

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample to avoid click on div

```
$("body :not(div)").click(function(){alert("Test")})
```

Answer (score 1):

as u use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').click(function(e) {
        if (e.target == this) { 
            alert('Parent was clicked');
        }
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ox8akcx/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `event.target` to determine where the user has clicked. Just ad the following snippet inside your event-listener for the body:

```
if($(e.target).is('div')){
    return false;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/no1fcsyg/)**

The `.is()` can of course be used with specific classed or other selectors.

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/no1fcsyg/1/)

**Reference**

[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/eaL53d62/1/

```
(function(){
    $('#body').on('mousedown', ':not(.not-clickable)', function(e){
        alert('clicked');
    });
}());
```

Specifically, using the :not() selector will ignore specific elements